# Custom navigation in maps

Tags: android, android-maps

How do I add a feature in the map activity in my Android app that allows users to move to the west, east, north, south of the map by clicking on buttons placed by me on the map?

The buttons are on the edge of the activity as shown in the pic [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6yxI.png).

Comment: just change the camera to the different directions on button clicks

Comment: please post your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case

```
int step = 100;
```

**Move east**

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(step, 0);
googleMap.moveCamera(update);
```

**Move west**

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(-step, 0);
googleMap.moveCamera(update);
```

**Move south**

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0, step);
googleMap.moveCamera(update);
```

**Move north**

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0, -step);
googleMap.moveCamera(update);
```